# Why won't the 'react-native -v' command run in my project directory?

Tags: react-native

When I enter `react-native -v` in my `react-native` project directory, all I get is command not found! How do I install this command?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the react native cli first, globally:

```
sudo npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Now you can enter 'react-native -v' at the command line from inside your project directory, and the version info for react native will appear correctly.

You can also see how react native is installed globally on your system (not just for the project) with

```
npm view react-native version
```